# How to update Django modelform without inserting?

Tags: django, modelform, updatemodel

I am having a problem with my Django code inserting new rows instead of updating existing ones. Many people on here have asked for help with a similar problem, but generally they forget about setting `instance` as in `form = SomeModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=some_model_instance)`. I seem to be doing that right, but it still doesn't save over existing data.

One other poster had the exact same issue (see [Django form INSERTs when I want it to UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376797/django-form-inserts-when-i-want-it-to-update)). It looks like the code given to him to fix the problem resolved the issue, but no one explained why it worked when he asked!

**VIEW**

```
   if form_type == "edit_event":
        # we need to load all the data based on the event_id
        event_id = request.POST['event_id'] or None
        event_to_edit = mapDataManager.getEvent(event_id)
        if event_to_edit and mapDataManager.userCreatedEvent(request.user, event_to_edit):
            # this user actually created this event
            # let them edit it
            event_form = EventModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=event_to_edit)
            location_form = LocationModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=event_to_edit.location)
            list_of_event_scheds = EventSchedule.objects.filter(pk=event_id).values()
            event_sched_formset = EventScheduleModelFormSet(request.POST or None, initial=list_of_event_scheds)

            if event_form and location_form and event_sched_formset:
                if event_form.is_valid() and location_form.is_valid() and event_sched_formset.is_valid():
                    # update event
                    mapDataManager.updateEvent(event_form, location_form, event_sched_formset)
                    # redirect
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('map'))
                else:
                    # set feedback to show edit event form
                    feedback = "edit_event"
```

**updateEvent()**

```
def updateEvent(self, event_form, location_form, event_sched_forms):

    event = event_form.save(commit=False)
    location = location_form.save()
    event.location = location
    event.save()
    for event_sched_form in event_sched_forms: # loop through formset
        event_sched = event_sched_form.save(commit=False)
        event_sched.event = event
        event_sched.save()
```

Can anyone help me out? Am I missing something really basic?

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, NONE of my forms were updating, all were inserting. Based on Daniel's suggestion I think I need to use formsets to link all three modelforms that are being edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the inline model formset working as per Daniel's suggestion with help from this blog post: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/djangos-inlineformsetfactory-and-you/

Just as an FYI, one crucial point I was missing is that the formset's instance refers to the parent model. Also, if you're displaying the formset manually in your template, don't forget to include {{ formset.id }}.

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reason, you're correctly passing `instance` to the main forms, but `initial` to EventScheduleModelFormSet, which is the immediate cause of the problem.

However, since these models obviously have a foreign key relationship, it sounds like you should be using a inline model formset:

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
eventschedule_formset_class = inlineformset_factory(Event, EventSchedule)
event_sched_formset = eventschedule_formset_class(request.POST or None,
                                                  instance=event_to_edit)
```

Now there is no need for that `updateEvent` logic - you can just save `event_sched_formset` and it will correctly reference the event.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll start using an inlineformset for event_sched then. But why are a new event and a new location being created? Those are not formsets, just modelforms. Do I need to use inlineformsets for everything since the three forms are related via foreign keys? Thanks very much!

Comment: You didn't make it clear in the question that that was the case. Anyway, are you sure that `request.POST['event_id']` exists and is not None?

Comment: Yes, `event_id` is being passed properly and `event_form` has both the new form data and an instance object. I tried to use your code but my inline formset class doesn't accept an instance and is throwing this error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'` at `event_sched_formset = EventScheduleModelFormSet(instance=event_form)`. I will lose access to the code until Sunday very soon so I might have to follow up with this later. Inline formset seems promising, however.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to save the EventScheduleModelFormSet form? there is no instance set only initial data so you are creating a new object every time. or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, I can't even update the event or the location. Nothing is getting updated, not even the modelforms.