# Override the save() method in Django ModelForm to create or update

Tags: python, django

**Intro:**

I want to override the save() method in my custom ModelForm to create a new row in a model or to update some data if it is exist. I have already found some solutions but it is implemented in the view function like this link [Django form INSERTs when I want it to UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376797/django-form-inserts-when-i-want-it-to-update), but I want to implement it in the form save() method.

**My Models:**

I have the default **auth.User** Model and my **Author** model as shown below, also I have another model called **UserAuthor** for the ManyToMany relationship between them as it is mandatory in my case for adding other fields like 'is_follow' and 'review'

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class UserAuthor(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        is_follow = models.BooleanField(default=0)
        review = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

**My Form:**

```
class ReviewFollowAuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAuthor
        fields = ("is_follow", "review")

    def save(self, commit=True, user=None, author=None):
        user_author = super(ReviewFollowAuthorForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user_author.user = user
        user_author.author = author
        if commit:
            user_author.save()
        return user_author
```

**My View:**

```
class ReviewFollowAuthor(View):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        author = get_object_or_404(Author, id=kwargs['pk'])
        f = ReviewFollowAuthorForm(request.POST)
        if(f.is_valid()):
            f.save(user=user,userx=userx)
            return JsonResponse({'success':1})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success':0})
```

In that case, it create a new row in the database for each save() call. I don't know how to check in the save method before saving, and just update in case there is a previous row for the requester user with the author, I tried many things but i failed. I know I can use:

```
user_author = UserAuthor.objects.filter(user=user, author=author)
```

**and update if it returns a result, but how in the save() method itself?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use django queryset `get_or_create()` method.

**From the docs:** This method is used for looking up an object with the given kwargs (may be empty if your model has defaults for all fields), creating one if necessary.

Read more about it [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Now, inside your view:

```
class ReviewFollowAuthor(View):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        author = get_object_or_404(Author, id=kwargs['pk'])
        #MAKE certain that user and author always have an instance within them.
        #send the user, author to the form.
        f = ReviewFollowAuthorForm(request.POST , user = user , author = author)
        if(f.is_valid()):
            f.save(user=user,userx=userx)
            return JsonResponse({'success':1})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success':0})
```

Now, inside your ModelForm:

```
class ReviewFollowAuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #override __init__ to make your "self" object have the instances sent by the your views.(author and user)
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user' , None)
        self.author = kwargs.pop('author' , None)
        #Now your model-form instance has the user and the author attribute within itself.
        super(ReviewFollowAuthorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = UserAuthor
        fields = ("is_follow", "review")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user_author, created = UserAuthor.objects.update_or_create( user=self.user, author=self.author, defaults={'is_follow': self.cleaned_data.get('is_follow'), 'review': self.cleaned_data.get('review')} )
        #rest of your logic
        return user_author
```

I Hope this guides you in some way.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but i get confused with you answer. You said that I can use  `get_or_create()` but where? Also, in the "except" case, the new record will be created with the extra fields from the POST request body. Great, but in the "try" case, how to update the fields of user_author without getting the fields from the request body individually?

Comment: @yassermohsen I have updated my answer and have tried to be a little more elaborate. Please check it.

Comment: It is working right now, Thank you. But I updated your code and I used `update_or_create()` method with the `defaults` attribute to be easier to update fields.
`def save(self, commit=True):
        user_author, created = UserAuthor.objects.update_or_create(
                user=self.user, author=self.author,
                defaults={'is_follow': self.cleaned_data.get('is_follow'), 'review': self.cleaned_data.get('review')}
            )
        return userxuser`
Please update it in ur answer to be clear for the others, and remove the user and the author from the save() method arguments

Comment: @yassermohsen thanks a lot. In fact even I didn't know that such a method existed. I always obtained the object through `get_or_create()` and then updated it. `update_or_create()` is clearly a better method for this use case. Thank you.

Comment: @yassermohsen between the comments and the answer I suppose we discussed and reached to a proper solution. If you want you can close the question(by checking the accept answer button) if you're satisfied. Or we can just leave this as is.

Comment: Sure we got the best answer together .. and I hope it may help others. IfI it is, you can vote for the answer or the question or leave this as is.

Comment: hi , please someone can help me to fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67658422/how-to-overwrite-save-method-in-django-model-form/67658893#67658893